# the intuition behind that the variance of increment for Brownian Motion is time interval

Tags: stochastic-processes, intuition

Could anybody help me to understand that why is that for Brownian motion, the variance of the increment $Z(t+s)-Z(t)$ is the time interval $s$?

I understand the math, but what is the intuition behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in terms of a discrete-time approximation of the process, the increment in a time interval $\delta t$ will have mean 0 and some variance.

If you sum up the contributions in non-overlapping time intervals they will be independent.

By [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) (specifically, $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are indepdendent) the variance of the total increment in $n$ such time intervals time $s=n\,\delta t$ will be the sum of the increment-variances and so will be proportional to the total length of the time interval $s$.

The process is defined so as to make that constant of proportionality $1$.

Comment: Hi thank you. This makes a lot sense. Especially about your last sentence - The process is defined so as to make that constant of proportionality  1. Do you mean that it is just by definition that the variance has such a relation with the time? If we want to extend the process to a specific case, we then could do it by modifying the basic BM?

Comment: @XueqiDong  That the variance is proportional to the time is obvious from the intuitive argument. That the constant of proportionality is 1 you can get from the mathematics. If you define a different process you could make the constant different, but it would just be a scaled brownian motion